# How to push a view controller using singleton methods

Tags: ios

I want to push a view controller when I press a button in common custom view which is added as subview in the `mainviewcontoller`. the method should be in singleton class to have the method commonly in all classes, How to do this please suggest me?

Is that possible to have the method in singleton class?

```
 CreateContactViewController *contactList = [self.storyboard     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"createContact"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:contactList animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get the UINavigationController instance of your visible view controller and push your view controller on it.

```
- (void)foo
{
     UIViewController *rootVC = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
     UINavigationController *nc = [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:rootVC].navigationController;
     if (nc) {
         CreateContactViewController *contactList = [nc.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"createContact"];
         [nc pushViewController:contactList animated:YES];
     } else {
         // Here is the case when the visible view controller is presented modally and not embedded in UINavigationController. 
         // So here you can ONLY present your new view controller modally.
         // Or dismiss the modally presented one and then push your new view controller
     }
}

- (UIViewController*)topViewControllerWithRootViewController: (UIViewController*)rootViewController
{
    if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {
        UITabBarController* tabBarController = (UITabBarController*)rootViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:tabBarController.selectedViewController];
    } else if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        UINavigationController* navigationController = (UINavigationController*)rootViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:navigationController.visibleViewController];
    } else if (rootViewController.presentedViewController) {
        UIViewController* presentedViewController = rootViewController.presentedViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:presentedViewController];
    } else {
        return rootViewController;
    }
}
```

Comment: Really thanks it's work for me,as a beginner it's help me a lot

Comment: Welcome! 
Then you can accept my answer that other users can surely use it ;)